# Spotlight search bar doesn't show up in middle of screen

Tags: macos, spotlight, search

For some reason, when I activate Spotlight, the bar shows up in the top right part of the screen instead of the middle. I've tried restarting and connecting to an external monitor, to no avail. [image: Screenshot of desktop]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Spotlight window remembers its last location. You can drag it back to the original location — it snaps to the X and Y coordinates of the initial position, so you can ensure it is back where it started.

If the Spotlight bar does not remember its last location, make sure `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Spotlight.plist` is writeable, as this plist file is where the coordinates are stored.

Answer (score 9):

Click and hold the Spotlight icon on the menu bar, until the Spotlight window has returned to its original location.